# Using re.sub with capture group references and numbers

Tags: python, regex, capture-group

Consider this simple MWE:

```
s = 'foo bar bar'
```

I'd like to use `re.sub` to change this to, say:

```
t = 'foo1 bar1 bar1'
```

If I wanted to append a suffix `X`, this would be pretty simple:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)\b', r'\1{}'.format('X'), s)
'fooX barX barX'
```

However, the problem arises when I try to substitute numbers:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)\b', r'\1{}'.format(1), s)
```

Because this gives an `error: invalid group reference`. Now, I understand why this is the case - the number is inserted into the string, and the string becomes `'\11'` which would refer to an invalid capture group.

Is there a way to use `re.sub` and get this working?

<sub>Note that this is just a simple example, and I'm not looking for an alternate solution.</sub>

Comment: Wow, that is a simple solution, thanks.

Comment: I recently [answered a question for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456706/escaping-numerals-in-string-replace/46457192#46457192) that had the same issue. You can create a callback function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218283/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-re-sub-callback) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094975/python-re-sub-question)

Comment: You can also try this, it worked for me: `final_s = re.sub('\s(?=\w)|$', '1 ', s)[:-1]` with output of `'foo1 bar1 bar1'`